# Creating jasmine unit test for angular directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, directive, karma-jasmine

The below directive checks/loads the template with value "pass, fail, required".
The conditions are

```
if(parent value == required){
1. if the value is true --> $scope.msg = "fail" --> loads the template with {{msg}} value
2. if the value is false --> $scope.msg = "pass" --> loads the template with {{msg}} value
}
```

In detail,

loading Template: [showerror.html]

```
<div>{{msg}}</div>
```

Directive Call:

```
<div show-error="obj"></div>
```

(obj contains as obj.error and obj.required )

Directive:

```
angular.module("dsf").directive('showError', [

    function () {
        'use strict';

        return {
            scope: {
                obj: '=showError'
            },
            link: function ($scope) {

                $scope.showError =  {};
                $scope.msg = "";

                function setTemplate(filename) {
                    $scope.showError.template = 'app/path/' + filename + '.html';
                }

                $scope.$watch(function () {

                    if ($scope.obj.required === true) {
                        if ($scope.obj.error === false) {
                            $scope.msg = "Pass";
                        } else if ($scope.obj.error === "required") {
                            $scope.msg = "Required";
                        } else if ($scope.obj.error === true) {
                            $scope.msg = "fail";
                        }

                    } else {

                        if ($scope.obj.error === true) {
                            $scope.msg = "fail";
                        } else if ($scope.obj.error === false) {
                            $scope.msg = "Pass";
                        }

                    }

                    setTemplate("showerror");
                });


            },
            template: '<div ng-include="showError.template"></div>'
        };
    }
]);
```

As i am new to jasmine test, how can i write the test for this directive? any suggestions?

Ok. I have written the unit test for this directive. What is the wrong now?

```
describe('showError', function () {
    'use strict';
    var compile, $scope, element;
    beforeEach(module('dsf'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        element = angular.element('<div show-error="obj"></div>');
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        compile = function (obj) {
            $scope.obj = obj;
            $compile(element)($scope);
            $scope.$digest();
        };
    }));
    it('updates the element when obj validation changes', function () {
        var obj;
        obj = {};
        $scope = compile(obj);
        $scope.apply(function () {
            obj.required = true;
            obj.error = true;
        });
        expect($scope.obj.msg).toContain('fail');
        $scope.apply(function () {
            obj.required = true;
            obj.error = false;
        });
        expect($scope.obj.msg).toContain('Pass');
        $scope.apply(function () {
            obj.required = true;
            obj.error = "required";
        });
        expect($scope.obj.msg).toContain('Required');
        $scope.apply(function () {
            obj.required = false;
            obj.error = true;
        });
        expect($scope.obj.msg).toContain('Pass');
        $scope.apply(function () {
            obj.required = false;
            obj.error = false;
        });
        expect($scope.obj.msg).toContain('fail');
    });
});
```

I am getting error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating $scopr.apply) error
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is `$scope.$apply()` not `$scope.apply()`.

Comment: yes. I got it. Can you tell me the test is right for this directory?